# how do I use a custom IUserRoleStore with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a Blazor server app internal to my company that uses our Azure AD for logins. This works, and it's great. This is what I do in `Startup` to enable this:

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);
```

But I have a legacy table in our database of role info for employees. What I'd like is for components like `AuthorizeView` and `[Authorize]` attribute to make use of the roles in this table based on the logged in user.

I made an implementation of `IUserRoleStore` that uses my custom table. If I pass the right `TUser` to it manually, then it works like I expect. But that works only for querying the role store manually. How do I make it so my custom role store is used by the `[Authorize]` attribute and `AuthorizeView` components?

I thought it might have to do with `services.AddIdentity`, but when I started down that road it broke my Azure AD integration, and led to a bunch of stuff it seemed I'd have to implement apart from my custom role store.

Comment: It's a long complicated answer, but you essentially need to add another authorization mechanism with policies with something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#policy-based-role-checks

Comment: thanks @BenSampica I did see some `policy`-based answers on similar questions. That did look a bit complicated, but I may revisit.